# JAX-RS @Path consolidation?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have paths that are similar and result in identical methods:

```
@GET
@Path("item/{favoriteList: AList }.{format}")
public Response list1(){return listFavorites();}

@GET
@Path("item/{favoriteList: AList }/{favoriteType: mumble}.{format}")
public Response list2(){return listFavorites();}
```

What's the 'best' way if any to consolidate these? I'm drawing a blank.

Ideally we'd be able to use multiple path annotations on a method, but there should be a way to do this short of two methods.

BTW-- don't shoot me over the paths, I have no control over them.

Thanks-- Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh

```
  @Path("item/{favoriteList: AList}{filler: (?:/mumble)?}.{format}")
```

There's no fool like a public fool.